# leaflet map not rendering in html document using rmarkdown

Tags: leaflet, r-markdown

Here is my code

````
---
date: "7 December 2018"
output: html_document
---

## 7 December 2018

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
library(jsonlite)
citibike <- fromJSON("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
stations <- citibike$stationBeanList
m = leaflet(stations) %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>% addCircles(lat = ~latitude, lng = ~longitude, weight = 5, radius = ~availableBikes, popup = paste("Station:", stations$stationName, "<br>", stations$availableBikes, "available bikes", "<br>", stations$availableDocks, "available docks")) %>% addControl("Available Bikes in NYC on 12/07/2018", position = "topright")
m
```
````

Using Knit, the html document created only shows the date but not the map. The map is created without any problem when using that code in the console of RStudio.

I have downloaded the latest version of leaflet from github. I use Windows 10.

> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32           arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32                      system         x86_64,
>   mingw32              status                                      major
>   3                            minor          5.1
>   year           2018                         month          07
>   day            02                           svn rev        74947
>   language       R                            version.string R version
>   3.5.1 (2018-07-02) nickname       Feather Spray

Comment: The map renders fine for me in MacOS using the latest versions of RStudio, R and all packages.

Comment: What browser did you use to see the html file? Also what version of leaflet do you use?

Comment: Works fine in RStudio viewer, Chrome and Firefox. `leaflet 2.0.2`

Comment: I don't understand as I have the same version of leaflet. It doesn't show either in RStudio viewer or Chrome. The only difference between us seems to be the OS.

Comment: Open the HTML in a browser, and check for errors in the console please.

Comment: Thanks but can you please be more specific?

Comment: In Firefox: *Menu -> Web Developer -> Web Console*. In Chrome it is similar. Check if there are any (red) errors.

Comment: Indeed the file rendered without a problem with Ubuntu operating system. I have the interactive map both on RStudio viewer as well as Chrome.